# Regular / Regular spacing between views for all iPads and iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, interface-builder

I've recently been encountering a difference in the regular / regular sizing class among different iPads, here's my related question [Regular / Regular position sizing constraints for all iPads, including iPad pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958858/regular-regular-position-sizing-constraints-for-all-ipads-including-ipad-pro)

Although I can use a multiplier and a constant to provide a margin, which is based on the device height, I can't now apply this approach to the spacing between views. Obviously, because I'm create a constraint between two views and can't therefore add the device height aka superview into the constraint.

I'm faced with having to add a clear / blank spacing view which is proportional height to the superview and pin my two views above and below it.

I'm looking for a different approach, is there one I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, all I'd need to do is follow the same approach as the other answer, and treat the top of the lower view as the top view. Then if I had problem with the top view views and lower view crashing into each other, then I could add a constraint with a priority.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried it this way:

In the below example I have two views. And I want spacing between them. 
The constriants on both views are.

view1:

- Top space
- Leading
- Trailing
- Proportional Height to superview(View1.height = 45% superview.height)

View2:

- Leading, Trailing, Bottom, Proportional Height to Superview(View2.height = 45% superView.height)

Here I did not fix the spacing between them. So Spacing will be different on different screen sizes.

So you divide your views heights in such a way that create spaces between them automatically.

This is one way. The other way is to use **priority** and **greater then or equal to**, **less then or equal to**, type of constraints.

Result on different devices:

IPHONE

[image]

IPAD 2 (50 % Zoom level)

[image]

IPAD PRO (50 % Zoom level)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the relation approach with items required in the constraint please? Both of my views are draw and replace images, so the aspect ratio is important, I believe the first approach would lose this ratio.

Comment: In this way we can set a vertical spacing between these two views. Edit the constraint and change = to >=.

Comment: Despite reading / watching tutorials I'm still confused about relations. I mean with => why isn't their a max value. I don't get how the constraint would increase.